# C++ program runs in background without admin rights

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, compilation

I was trying to remove the console window that opens when starting c++ programs with regular main function and still keep it while compiling for debug so i can send output to the console.
To test this i was using a simple engine i wrote using OpenGL 4.6.

What i ended up doing is this (I'm using windows and the msvc compiler):

- Compile the the debug version with the compiler option `/DDEBUG`
- Have a pragma in my main source file that adds `/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup` if the debug flag is not set.

```
#ifndef DEBUG
  #pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")
#endif
```

Now what ends up happening is, in Debug mode everything works fine, but in Release mode the window of my application does not show and it just creates a process running in the background which i have to manually kill.
If i run it as an administrator, the application works fine in release mode.

Thus the question:

Why does it need admin rights in release mode (without terminal) but doesnt need them with a terminal?
And how can i work around this? I would rather not have my application need admin rights to run.

Comment: Can you remove the `#ifndef DEBUG`, so you have the same application like in Release and try to debug the application? Maybe OpenGL throws some errors, that you cannot see, because of a non-existent console, when having no admin rights

Comment: This is generally considered bad form - your program doesn't need to decide this; the way you start the program can.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Thats a good idea, i will try that.

Comment: @UKMonkey Sorry, but i can't make out what exactly is bad form from your comment.

Comment: @DJSchaffner having your binary decide what to do with the console.   What happens if it's run from the console? What do you expect to happen?  The correct thing to do is rather than try and change your program to control how it starts, you find how you're starting the program, and then change that.

Comment: @UKMonkey either i'm misunderstanding you, or you misunderstood what i did here. I put that into the source code, which gets evaluated during compilation so the binary doesnt decide anything during runtime. If i open the program from a console i'm expecting the same thing as when i launch it by clicking on it. Open a window and display whatever i put into the draw routine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your define needs to `_NDEBUG`, but there seems to be a better way to approach this problem.

You should keep the default `wWinMain` entry point, not the UCRT entry point, all the arguments are shifted by one. So try this instead to write to the console:

Keep compiling with the subsystem set to `WINDOWS`, and remove the `/ENTRY` flag. Use `wWinMain` instead. Add this to open the console.

```
AllocConsole();
freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);
freopen("CONOUT$", “w”, stdout);
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);

wprintf(L"Console out write command.\r\n");
```

Comment: I was using the UCRT entry point to just keep a regular main function instead of using the windows specific options. Is there no cross-platform solution to this? I will try if your solution works, but it looks like its really "hacky"

Comment: Well in that case you can just set ‘/ENTRY’ to ‘CONSOLE’ and hide the console window on startup by using ‘ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE):’